# WPF MVVM - Binding DataGrid to ObservableCollection of Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I am pretty new to WPF MVVM, so pardon me if I understood MVVM concepts wrongly.

I have a `DataGrid` in my View, which I have bound the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<M>` in the ViewModel. The `M` class is a Model class. However, the `M` class has `bool` properties, which are to be displayed in the DataGrid as `"Yes/No"` strings.

Currently, I am using a Converter to convert the `bool` value to `string`. But, it just feels wrong for the ViewModel to expose a list `(ObservableCollection)` of a Model to the View. I have also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334126/should-the-mvvm-viewmodel-perform-type-conversion-validation) that in MVVM, conversions should be done at ViewModel. So, what is the right way to implement this the MVVM way for a `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

In an **ideal** world, you would wrap your `Model` objects in their own `ViewModel` so that your `ObservableCollection` contains a `ViewModel` type with those `bool` `Model` properties converted to Yes/No `string` properties.

However, in a **pragmatic** world, if you are not editing those values, I wouldn't bother except to note that if you are exposing many of those `bool` properties and have many thousands of rows, you will take a performance hit on rendering the grid while the `DataGrid` instantiates a `Converter` per property and row.

Comment: The `AutoGenerateColumns` property is set to false, and I am defining my own Columns. So in columns definitions, the converters are `StaticResources`, I don't think it instantiates multiple `Converters` right?

Comment: I am also thinking of binding to `Observable<ViewModel>`, but for my case, I do know that the table (DataGrid) will definitely and always have a single row (meaning to say that it will always have only one model instance). I almost wanted to just hard-code this in ViewModel by totally not implement a Model for it, but I stopped myself when I think of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Using converters is not a wrong way. As per my suggestion, you should bind the data as you're doing now and in the view you can create and use a **BoolToStringConverter** for converting the boolean value to yes or no.

Comment: Yup, I have already a `BoolToYesNoConverter`, but I just feel weird that the View knows about Model properties and is directly manipulating them. Kind of couples the View to the Model.

Comment: That is not coupling. That is your requirement. When the model is updated the view should be updated. That sync keeps your application alive.

Comment: It's the normal way to do things in MVVM. However if you are comfortable doing the conversion in the view model, it will be fine too. Get  a string property to bind to the field and when you're getting value from the database from your view model, you could do the conversion.